# Populate a combobox with tables of a database in VB

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, combobox

I want to populate my combobox with the name of the tables of my database "converter" that has 3 tables. I'm using the following code:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=NewPass;database=converter"
    Try
        conn.Open()

        command.Connection = conn
        command.CommandText = "SHOW TABLES"

        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, conn)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(dt)

        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "column_name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "column_name"

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

This code populates 3 items inside the combobox (which is the same as the number of tables inside my database). But what shows is this:

[image: Error]

How can I populate my combobox with the exact name of my tables and not like this? I tried putting .toString on my dt but it's no good.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance. :)

**EDIT**
I used Steve's method and I was able to get the values. I used this code.

```
conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=NewPass;database=converter"
    Try
        conn.Open()

        command.Connection = conn
        command.CommandText = "SHOW TABLES"

        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, conn)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        dt = conn.GetSchema("TABLES")
        adapter.Fill(dt)

        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "table_name"

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

But now it shows 3 additional empty values. refer to this image:

[image: ERROR 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right the correct values to pass to your combobox DisplayMember and ValueMember is

```
Tables_in_converter
```

In other words, the name of the only column returned by your command is built automatically using the fixed text `"Tables_in_"`  followed by the `<databasename>`

If you want to use a different approach you could call the GetSchema method of the connection object in this way

```
using cnn = new MySqlConnection(...)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim dt = cnn.GetSchema("TABLES")

    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "table_name"
End Using
```

Comment: I used your code and It worked but it now shows 3 extra "empty" items. I edited my question.

Comment: My methods are in alternative to each other. You should choose between the SHOW TABLES approach or the GetSchema approach. As you have written above you call both and of course the rows are duplicated with the combo in utter confusion about which value to show. Remove the code relative to the adapter part

Comment: Oh I see. I removed the adapter part and It worked fine. Thank you so much :)